# SQL Query Help (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a query. I have the following 3 tables:

```
documents (
    id,
    title
);

positions (
    id,
    title
);

documents_positions (
    document_id,
    position_id
);
```

What I am trying to get (my requested outcome) is a matrix of documents, and what positions they apply to. So each row would have document title, and then have a column for every position and a column next to it with True or False if the positions applies to the document. I suspect some kind of LEFT JOIN is required, because on each row after document, I want to list every position from the positions table and whether or not the document applies to it. Make sense?

Comment: Can you provide input data and expected outcome data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `cross join` to build the matrix, and then `left join` to find the positions in the matrix that are filled:

```
select  d.title
,       p.title
,       case when dp.document_id is null then 'hrmm' else 'HALLELUJAH' end
from    documents d
cross join
        positions p
left join
        documents_positions dp
on      dp.document_id = d.id
        and dp.position_id = p.id
```

Comment: This gives me the correct data, but how can I have the output be where each position is on the same row as the document?

Comment: @Pyrite: That's called "pivoting".  Excel can do that for you, or most other reporting tools.  SQL doesn't like a variable number of columns, making pivoting next to impossible to do in pure SQL.

Comment: I guess I mean to say, how to PIVOT the results in Postgresql?

Comment: It seems to PIVOT in Postgresql is to manually define each position in the SQL query, but this is not an option, unless it can be done dynamically. So I think I should just implement the output in the client application (in my case, an HTML table using PHP). So the question remains, how to do that I guess.

Comment: @Pyrite: `order by p.id, d.id`.  Then add a new column for every row from the database, and a new row every time the position changes.

Comment: FYI: I got it working like you said, and it's awesome! So happy to learn about CROSS JOIN AND PIVOT.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to turn `positions` rows into columns you have to "pivot" them. In PostgreSQL this is done with [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) function. However, `crosstab` seems to require that you define the number of output columns in the query which you can't do as the number of rows in the `positions` is subject to change? 
I'm not a PostgreSQL user myself so perhaps there is some trick to build the dynamic query I don't know of but it seems to be easier to use query like Andomar posted and then pivot the rows in your client code...